# How to display info from dataGrid by Selected the Row and show it to its box in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, dbcontext

Problem: Cannot retrieve id, name and image from datagrid to its boxes.

I Tried the Code Below how to display id, name and image on its boxes by Select from the dataGrid especially the image which has been save on a database as byte.

```
        private void Personlist_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        DataGrid gd = (DataGrid)sender;
        DataRowView row_selected = gd.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
        if (row_selected != null)
        {
            IDtextbox.Text = row_selected["Id"].ToString();
            Nametextbox.Text = row_selected["Name"].ToString();

           ***// i need here to write a row for image.*** 

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the SelectionChangedEventArgs e to retrieve the selected items.

There is a member called 'AddedItems'.
- In case of single-selection this always hold the one currently selected item.
- In case of multi-selection, it holds those items, which were currently added to the DataGrid-selection.

So, your code could look something like this:

```
private void DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.AddedItems != null && e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        DataRowView row_selected = e.AddedItems[0] as DataRowView;
        if (row_selected != null)
        {
            IDtextbox.Text = row_selected["Id"].ToString();
            Nametextbox.Text = row_selected["Name"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Is your DataGrid filled with some data at all?

You could use some debug-data in the constructor of your app like

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Id");
dt.Columns.Add("Name");
dt.Columns.Add("Pic");

DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["Id"] = "1";
dr["Name"] = "You";
dr["Pic"] = "0x5234265";
dt.Rows.Add(dr);

dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["Id"] = "2";
dr["Name"] = "Me";
dr["Pic"] = "0x000202";
dt.Rows.Add(dr);

theDataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

Perhaps you can post a little more code, because I still cannot figure out, what your question actually is about?

And generally, WPF-Binding would be nicer to fill you UI elements with data.

Comment: thank you, but also doesn't work, maybe first should i add a row for image box ... do you know how ?

Comment: Well, I think I don't get exactly, what you mean...  Do you mean, that you cannot fetch the data from the (whole) selected DaraGrid-row (as your 1st question asked), so the whole ```gd.SelectedItem as DataRowView``` was empty?  Or do you mean, that the data for your image is empty?

Comment: the whole boxes(text & image boxes) still empty when i select a row from DataGridView by mouse click

Comment: Updated my first answer by some more details/additional questioning about your problem.